# Which is the optimum method to use jbpm?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, drools, jbpm, kie

I found that kie- workbench, eclipse plugin and drools workbench are different ways to make use of jbpm functionalities. But, which is the least error-prone and time-saving method of all available?

Comment: The one you know best.

Comment: Report errors on the Drools Jira site - don't mention them here. Also, don't dwell on your achievements and hopes - this is not the place for it.

Comment: Thanks for telling but I have already mentioned them there. I am working on kie-workbench. Also, I have just started with jbpm. So, there isn't any best I know of. Can you suggest a method of good practice?

Answer (score 0):

The Drools workbench IS the KIE workbench. When your question is just what is more useful when designing business processes, there is no valid answer because, like laune has said, this is an emotional question and not a technical one: one person thinks this and the other thinks that.

That said, you can use both IDE and workbench at the same time with the IDE connecting to your local KIE workbench repository, pushing changes and the KIE workbench pulling these changes. Just use the indications in the documention to find out how to.